# Horizontal ScrollView crops long text

Tags: react-native, scrollview

My goal is to get a newsflash component with animations.
I'm implementing a View that contains moving text.

The ScrollView does perform well the animation, however, the inner text doesn't displayed from the start:

```
<Animated.View style={flex: 4}>
      <ScrollView
         style={{flex: 1 }}
         horizontal={true}
         scrollEnabled={false}
         contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 }}>

        <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft }}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1}>{this.props.subtitle}</Text>
        </Animated.View>

   </ScrollView> 
</Animated.View>
```

I tried almost every variation of flex and flexGrow and more but nothing doesn't work well.
If I'm removing the ScrollView it shows well the text, but the effect looks bad.

In the picture, you can see the bottom text cropped (fami)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out with removing the flex: 1 from the views and adding:

```
onContentSizeChange={this.scrollListToStart}
```

that will run only once at the start using a state variable.